# What is the difference between table-per-service and schema-per-service?

Tags: microservices

My question should be self explanatory but I am learning about microservices and the three types of database configurations to use with them-

1. Database-per-service
2. Schema-per-service
3. Table-per-service

Assigning each service it's own database is an easy concept to understand but I am failing to understand the distinction between 2 and 3 and all my googling returns the similarly vague explanations - a private set of tables vs a private schema, isn't that basically the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, a schema is a set of tables.

You can use table-per-service, you need to prefix the tables of each service by the name of the service to know which table belongs to which service (service foo => tables foo_A, foo_B, ...). You can use schema-per-service, the schema has the name of the service, and you can name the tables as you want (service foo => schema foo with tables foo.A, foo.B, ... When you're inside the 'foo' schema you can just invoke A, B, ...).

Concerning security, a good practice is to create a user for each service, and you restrict the user to the tables of the service. It is easier and safer to assign those restrictions on a schema than on each table. When you add a table, you risk to forget to set the restrictions. If you add a table to a schema, the restrictions of the schema are applies.

So I would recommend to use schema-per-service over table-per-service.